# Download button not working in wordpress website. How can solve it?

Tags: wordpress

Download link is not working in my WordPress website. File, link address everything is correct. Even by right click the file is opening in other tab. But it is not downloading directly. How to solve this problem?

I have cleared the cache of the website. But nothing happened.